# My alert function should clear the previous search result and then display new one

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have wriiten the below code in which the city the alert function initially works fine when a wrong city name or no city name is entered. But after the Weather details are displayed here again when I click on submit then it re renders the previous state and new one and gives both result.

Code:

```
import React, { FC, useState, FormEvent } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Header, Input, Button } from "../style";
import {
  getWeather,
  setLoading
} from "../../store/actions/WeatherAction/weatherActions";
import { setAlert } from "../../store/actions/AlertAction/alertActions";

interface SearchProps {
  title: string;
}

const Search: FC<SearchProps> = ({ title }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [city, setCity] = useState("");

  const changeHandler = (e: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setCity(e.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const submitHandler = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    dispatch(setLoading());
    dispatch(getWeather(city));
    setCity("");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Header>
        {title}
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <Input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter city name"
            value={city}
            onChange={changeHandler}
          />
          <br />
          <Button>Search</Button>
        </form>
      </Header>
    </>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

weatherAction.ts

```
import { ThunkAction } from "redux-thunk";
import { RootState } from "../..";
import {
  WeatherAction,
  WeatherData,
  WeatherError,
  GET_WEATHER,
  SET_LOADING,
  SET_ERROR
} from "../../types";

export const getWeather = (
  city: string
): ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, WeatherAction> => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=3020950b62d2fb178d82816bad24dc76`
      );
      if (!res.ok) {
        const resData: WeatherError = await res.json();
        throw new Error(resData.message);
      }

      const resData: WeatherData = await res.json();

      dispatch({
        type: GET_WEATHER,
        payload: resData
      });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: SET_ERROR,
        payload: err.message
      });
    }
  };
};

export const setLoading = (): WeatherAction => {
  return {
    type: SET_LOADING
  };
};

export const setError = (): WeatherAction => {
  return {
    type: SET_ERROR,
    payload: ""
  };
};
```

weatherReducer

```
import {
  WeatherState,
  WeatherAction,
  GET_WEATHER,
  SET_LOADING,
  SET_ERROR
} from "../../types";

const initialState: WeatherState = {
  data: null,
  loading: false,
  error: ""
};

export default (state = initialState, action: WeatherAction): WeatherState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_WEATHER:
      return {
        data: action.payload,
        loading: false,
        error: ""
      };
    case SET_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case SET_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure exactly what your problem is or how the screenshot is related. Can you please add details and show us specifically what is wrong? We may need to see your actions / resolvers.

Comment: We need to see dispatch action and reducer to help u.

Comment: @BudgieInWA when the page is loaded initially, if I put an incorrect city name the I get an alert message likewise if I don't put any city name I get alert message too. But if I put a valid city name then I get the weather data of the particular city. My API is working fine till this point. But after this if I try to put a wrong city name I get the alert message and previous city data too as mentioned in the image mentioned. I have added the action as well as the reducer here. Could you please help me out.

Comment: @soufianebth I have added the action and reducer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your reducer does not clear the weather data when processing a `SET_ERROR` action. If you want to clear the weather data when you receive an error, you should set `data` back to `null` like this:

```js
case SET_ERROR:
      return {
        data: null,
        error: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
```